# Descargar Archivo de Google Gmail APi

Tags: javascript, gmail

mediante la función

```
 var request = gapi.client.gmail.users.messages.attachments.get({
              'id': attachId,
              'messageId': message.id,
              'userId': userId
            });
```

consigo una respuesta JSON así:

```
{
  "attachmentId": string,
  "size": integer,
  "data": bytes
}
```

Como descargo ese archivo? o hay alguna funcion para bajar esos attachments files desde la api de gmail-google

También tengo acceso a message.payload.parts y esto me trae el siguiente JSON:

```
 {
        "partId": "0.1",
        "mimeType": "image\/jpeg",
        "filename": "image001.jpg",
        "headers": [
          {
            "name": "Content-Type",
            "value": "image\/jpeg; name=\"image001.jpg\""
          },
          {
            "name": "Content-Description",
            "value": "image001.jpg"
          },
          {
            "name": "Content-Disposition",
            "value": "inline; filename=\"image001.jpg\"; size=1741; creation-date=\"Tue, 03 Oct 2017 15:46:00 GMT\"; modification-date=\"Tue, 03 Oct 2017 15:46:00 GMT\""
          },
          {
            "name": "Content-ID",
            "value": "<image001.jpg@01D33C31.F1009E50>"
          },
          {
            "name": "Content-Transfer-Encoding",
            "value": "base64"
          }
        ],
        "body": {
          "attachmentId": "ANGjdJ-DGT4IBENdLsJvn6uXAioxfrLQ7TCLWY6f5i5i0bAzQwHvlMhKxpa7IP6xK1XzlLkCykgDRuyPpa15LO37MAmVrmskWjNz0VMEIE0O7DwKAffXTnnrs5essp6usU6JlHfhBL8zDlVMKSaPiYdnRWZ3TQWF6XhHgXbc2saStJULHufsYf66Xcon6GIvFp2Yy66eBXhMcKA_PV7aFEDrY_aDOVBphUdP2nfjlnRJJfDbnXotXd_OYDjk00Hv0IL-sNAwu1ZEzRSCitdzxkD6GqLBbhHIEdZV_N0U0vNMukbJRDSIls2ljFMHoLyvdz5p6njPBAd-Ck7HWdYnQ26gGojUwSKx2j4G5BSfmGExeDCfFpqPn2oLJxWoG-fLtUJ1cALXOx9gBi3_hmZK",
          "size": 1741
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```

_______________________________-
**Actualización** :

Consegui Descargar los Archivos, Sin embargo tengo una duda más, cómo hago para colocarle el nombre que me trae el json al archivo, ya que al descargarlo me sale **descarga.ext**

**`window.location = 'data:'+part.mimeType+';base64,'+resp.data.replace(/-/g, '+').replace(/_/g, '/');`**

Comment: Que bien que logras resolver tu duda original. Lo ideal es que publiques la solución como respuesta y la pregunta de seguimiento como una nueva pregunta. ¿Te animas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Lo pude resolver de la siguiente forma (funcional para todos los formatos de archivos):**

```
downloadFile(attachmentID, emailID, mimeType, name) {
      this.$axios
        .$get('endpoint', {
          params: {
            email: emailID,
            file: attachmentID,
          },
        })
        .then((response) => {
          const linkSource = `data:${mimeType};base64,${response.data
            .replace(/-/g, '+')
            .replace(/_/g, '/')}`
          const downloadLink = document.createElement('a')
          const fileName = name
          downloadLink.href = linkSource
          downloadLink.download = fileName
          window.open(downloadLink.href, '_blank')
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.error(error)
        })
    },
```